# How can I access gets and sets in a sub class?

Tags: java, polymorphism, downcast, upcasting

In this application we have the Automovel class:

```
public class Automovel {
    private String marca;
    private String matricula;
    private String anoConstrucao;
    private Motor motor;
    private int preco = 0;
}
```

(with their builders, getters and setters) and there is a class called Motor that is an attribute of the Automovel class.

Motor Class:

```
private int potencia;

    public Motor() {}

    public Motor(int potencia){
        this.potencia = potencia;
    }

    public int getPotencia() {return this.potencia;}

    public void setPotencia(int potencia) {
        this.potencia = potencia
}
```

There are also 2 subclasses of this class (MotorEletrico and MotorCombustao):

Motor Elétrico:

```
public class MotorEletrico extends Motor {

    private int autonomia;
    public MotorEletrico() {}

    public MotorEletrico(int potencia, int autonomia) {
        super(potencia);
        this.autonomia = autonomia;
    }

    public int getAutonomia() {
        return autonomia;
    }

    public void setAutonomia(int autonomia) {
        this.autonomia = autonomia;
    }

}
```

Motor Combustão:

```
public class MotorCombustao extends Motor{

    private int cilindrada;
    private String combustivel;

    public MotorCombustao(){}

    public MotorCombustao(int potencia, int cilindrada, String combustivel){
        super(potencia);
        this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
        this.combustivel = combustivel;
    }

    public int getCilindrada(){
        return cilindrada;
    }

    public void setCilindrada(int cilindrada){
        this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
    }

    public String getCombustivel(){
        return combustivel;
    }

    public void setCombustivel(String combustivel){
        this.combustivel = combustivel;
    } 
}
```

I store a car with an X engine in an array of Automovel objects, but when I try to access the getters and setters of the subclass (MotorCombustao / MotorEletrico), only the gets and sets of the mother class (Motor) appears. My problem is that I can't access the getters and setters of the motor subclasses. 
Here's an example of what I tried:

Automovel arrayteste[] = new Automovel[49];

```
Motor motor1 = new MotorEletrico();
motor1.setPotencia(5);

Automovel automovel1 = new Automovel("Opel", "xx-12-xx", "2000", motor1, 2000);

arrayteste[0] = automovel1;

System.out.println(arrayteste[0].getMotor().getPotencia()); //Here, I can't Do .getAutonomia
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that you "can't Do .getAutonomia"?

Comment: my evidence is that when i put .getMotor().get it doesnt show any stu in MotorEletrico or MotorCombustao

Comment: Stepping back a second, when you're following LSK like this `Parent obj = new Child();`, you'll be referring to an instance of Parent when invoking `obj`. Under the hood, it's still `Child` and can be cast to such, but the idea is to share common functionality in the parent class so you don't even need to downcast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the reference of the parent class to the corresponding child class **if you want to access a method which is not inherited from the parent class** e.g. the method, `getAutonomia()` is not inherited from `Motor` and therefore, you need to cast the reference of `Motor` to `MotorEletrico` before you can access  `getAutonomia()`. Some more useful code is given below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Automovel arrayteste[] = new Automovel[2];
        Motor motor;

        motor = new MotorEletrico(5, 10);
        arrayteste[0] = new Automovel("Opel", "xx-12-xx", "2000", motor, 2000);

        motor = new MotorCombustao(7, 4, "xx-yy-zz");
        arrayteste[1] = new Automovel("Opel", "xx-08-xx", "1995", motor, 1995);

        for (Automovel automovel : arrayteste) {
            motor = automovel.getMotor();
            if (motor instanceof MotorEletrico) {
                System.out.println(((MotorEletrico) motor).getAutonomia());
            }
            if (automovel.getMotor() instanceof MotorCombustao) {
                System.out.println(((MotorCombustao) motor).getCilindrada());
                System.out.println(((MotorCombustao) motor).getCombustivel());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10
4
xx-yy-zz
```

---

**[Update:** the following update is based on your comment]

Another way to iterate `arrayteste` is as given below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayteste.length; i++) {
    if (arrayteste[i] != null) {
        motor = arrayteste[i].getMotor();
        if (motor instanceof MotorEletrico) {
            System.out.println(((MotorEletrico) motor).getAutonomia());
        }
        if (arrayteste[i].getMotor() instanceof MotorCombustao) {
            System.out.println(((MotorCombustao) motor).getCilindrada());
            System.out.println(((MotorCombustao) motor).getCombustivel());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: im gonna test and try to implement it in my code, thanks

Comment: i have another problem, i need print the hole array, but it doenst mean that all positions will have info, they maybe will be as null. how can i print the whole array withou using (Automovel automovel : arrayteste)?

Comment: it gives me an error because most of the array its empty, i use a array with 50 spaces

Comment: I have posted an update. Let me know in case of any further update.

Comment: i changed my code to an arraylist what you think is better array list or array?

Comment: The advantage of `ArrayList` over an array is that it is not of fixed size and its API is very rich. If you want to work with a list of unknown size, you should use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: im gonna use an array because i remeber that i should only have 50 car its the maximum

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

You need to cast

```
System.out.println(((MotorElettrico)(arrayteste[0].getMotor())).getAutonomia());
```

**TL;DR**

When you wrote

```
Motor motor1 = new MotorElettrico();
```

you are using *polymorphism*.

This is very useful when, for example you, have a list of `Motor` that contains more then one motor type and for all of this you want to print the `potencia`.

Then you can write something like this:

```
List<Motor> list = Arrays.asList(new MotorElectico(), new MotorCombustao());
// ----- some set

print(list);
```

where print method is something like this:

```
public void print(List<Motor> list){
    for(Motor m : list){
        System.out.println(String.format("Potencia %d", m.getPotencia()));
    }
}
```

This happens because a MotorElectico *IS A* Motor and *upcasting* (casting to supertype) is always allowed.

In your case, you have to do *downcasting*: you are telling to a compilator that `arraytest[0].getMotor()` contains a `Motor` but this `Motor` is actually a `MotorElectrico`: you are asking to compilator to trust you. If at compile-time `arraytest[0].getMotor()` should not be a `MotorElectrico` you'd get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Yes, Base b = new Sub(); ((Sub) b).subMethod() ; is possible

Comment: im gonna test this

Comment: but my array or array list needs to be as an Automovel object otherwise i can save automovel object with Motor and MotorCombustao/MotorEletrico

Answer (score 0):

You are familiar with the [Liskov substitution principle](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov), I assume.
If you don't know the type of motor, you can write a statement that asks each instance of the Automovel array `arraytest[i]` what class it is.
For example:

```
    List<Automovel> arrayteste = new ArrayList<>();

    Motor motor1 = new MotorEletrico();
    motor1.setPotencia(5);

    Automovel automovel1 = new Automovel("Opel", "xx-12-xx", "2000", motor1, 2000);

    arrayteste.add(automovel1);

    Motor motor = new Motor();
    String motorClass;
    String[] motorTypes = {"MotorEletrico", "MotorCombustao"};
    Set<String> motorClasses = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(motorTypes));

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayteste.size(); i++)
    {
        motorClass = arrayteste.get(i).getMotor().getClass().getName();
        if (motorClasses.contains(motorClass))
        {
            if (motorClass.equals("MotorEletrico"))
            {
                motor = (MotorEletrico)(arrayteste.get(i).getMotor());
            }
            else if (motorClass.equals("MotorCombustao"))
            {
                motor = (MotorCombustao)(arrayteste.get(i).getMotor());
            }
            System.out.println("Automovel #" + i + " : " + motor.getPotencia());
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Não sei que classe de motor é esse . . .");
        }
     }
}
```

But it might be better to explore the class design more closely. 
Possibly try to use interfaces.

Comment: Sorry. I hit the wrong key before the answer was written. Look at edited response.